# Hec Ras error while processing

Tags: hec-ras

I am facing this error while creating a new terrain in Hec RAS ? 
Importing 1 of 1: dem_rep.tif
Step 1 of 4: Translating to GeoTiff with SRS...
Error creating Terrain: The system cannot find the file specified
Cleaning up files...
How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Facing a problem during the terrain creation I discovered that the procedure does not hanlde file paths with special characters. If the path has a special character like spaces and letters like ä ö Å ñ and so on, then it fails.

The solution is to move temporarly the project to any location (folder) without special characters and once the terrain is created move it back the terrain to th project folder.